# Algorithm to figure out which links to follow in wikipedia

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, neural-network, web-crawler, probability

Starting at a given wiki page, I wish to find the pages whose concepts comprise the original. For example, from "computer", I would like to travel to links "Hard drive" or "CPU". I have a list of all links. Some relevant others not. How would I assign a probability of "goodness" to each link?

Comment: This seems useful https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.01427.pdf

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.